# ssh, how to specify a key file which is on another machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I need to ssh to a remote host 2 when I am "sshed" in other remote machine (remote host 1). For example, from remote host1 I need to execute:

```
ssh -i MY_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME myname@remotehost2
```

However, my private key file is on my local machine. How can I specify it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ssh agent to forward your local key.

Start your agent (should be already installed) with

```
ssh-agent
```

then add your local key

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/keyfile.key
```

then login to serverA

```
ssh -A userA@serverA
```

Now you should be able to login at serverB with you local key.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- `scp` the key to remote host 1
- Copy the key manually, i.e. copy locally, open an editor on remote host 1, paste, save.
- Connect to remote host 2 from a different local terminal (or drop the connection in the one you're on)
- Set up ssh forwarding. I *believe* it would be something like `ssh -R 12345:remotehost2:22 user@remotehost1`, then from local `ssh -p 12345 user@remotehost1`. Note that `user` in the second command is the username for `remotehost2`, despite apparently connecting to 1.